# Не понимаю,как исправить ошибку(подсвечено оранжевым цветом и снизу комментарий"Все элементы...")

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

````
export default class Card {
  constructor(data, cardSelector) {
    this._title = data.name;
    this._imageLink = data.link;
    this._cardSelector = cardSelector;
    this._element = this._getTemplate();
  }


_scaleImage(evt) {
    const popupForScaleImg = document.querySelector(".popup_for_scale-image");
    const formImg = document.querySelector(".popup__image");
    const formImgTitle = document.querySelector(".popup__image-title");
    formImg.src = evt.target.src;
    formImg.alt = evt.target.alt;
    formImgTitle.textContent = evt.target.alt;

    return openPopup(popupForScaleImg);
  } ```
````

Comment: ...какую ошибку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы по-русски напишите что не так, а не "подсвечено оранжевым цветом и снизу комментарий"Все элементы...".......на картинке ошибки нет.... проблема не ясна.....если не напишите - вопрос закроют

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вот так имелось ввиду:

```js
export default class Card {
  constructor(data, cardSelector) {
    this._title = data.name;
    this._imageLink = data.link;
    this._cardSelector = cardSelector;
    this._element = this._getTemplate();
    
    this.popupForScaleImg = document.querySelector(".popup_for_scale-image");
    this.formImg = document.querySelector(".popup__image");
    this.formImgTitle = document.querySelector(".popup__image-title");
  }


  _scaleImage(evt) {
    this.formImg.src = evt.target.src;
    this.formImg.alt = evt.target.alt;
    this.formImgTitle.textContent = evt.target.alt;

    return openPopup(this.popupForScaleImg);
  }
}
```

Получение элементов (`.popup_for_scale-image` и тд) записаны в свойства класса.
Теперь при вызове метода `_scaleImage` элементы берутся из свойства класса, а не ищутся каждый раз заново